What is this data type T$ACTION_REL_TABLE?
could you help me with my problem. I came across a field type unfamiliar to me - T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE in the table and this table does not work through SELECT, although VIEWS related to this table work. All this happens through accessing a remote database via PL SQL Developer, Objects - Database links
enter image description here

You can work out what it is from the data dictionary:
SELECT object_name, object_type
FROM   USER_OBJECTS
WHERE  object_name = 'T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE';

Which may output:



OBJECT_NAME
OBJECT_TYPE




T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE
TYPE



Or, if it is not in your own schema you can query ALL_OBJECTS:
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  object_name = 'T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE';

Which may output:



OWNER
OBJECT_NAME
OBJECT_TYPE




SCHEMA_NAME
T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE
TYPE




I had created the object using:
CREATE TYPE T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(42);

So the data dictionary queries show it as a TYPE. If that is the case for you then you can get more details using:
SELECT type_name, typecode
FROM   USER_TYPES
WHERE  type_name = 'T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE';

Which for my type outputs:



TYPE_NAME
TYPECODE




T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE
COLLECTION



Which tells you that, for the type I created, it is a collection (array) data-type (your data-type may be different).
Or, again if it is not in your own schema:
SELECT owner, type_name, typecode
FROM   ALL_TYPES
WHERE  type_name = 'T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE';

Which outputs:



OWNER
TYPE_NAME
TYPECODE




SCHEMA_NAME
T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE
COLLECTION




If you want to see the DDL statement for the type then:
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 'TYPE', 'T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE', 'SCHEMA_NAME' ) AS ddl
FROM   DUAL;

Which outputs:



DDL




CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE "SCHEMA_NAME"."T$ACTION_REAL_TABLE" IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(42)



fiddle
